# cdo: redefine time axis from fractional year to month

Tags: cdo-climate

Hi I have a file with the time dimension in fractional years like this:

```
[-5039.         -5038.91650391 -5038.83349609 -5038.75  -5038.66650391
-5038.58349609 -5038.5        -5038.41650391 -5038.33349609 -5038.25
-5038.16650391 -5038.08349609]
```

Each time step corresponds to one month from 1 to 12.

How can I change the time dimension from the fractional years above to

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

in cdo?

I tried it with settaxis, and settime but maybe I did it wrong.
Thanks for your help!